# Move in the same angle from point to point?

Tags: java, android, trigonometry, angle

I need to be able to move my player x and y pixels in the same direction as a point to a point. It's hard to explain, but this is what I am trying to do:

[image]

Angles 1 and 2 have to be the same. Point 1 stays the same at (100, 100), however point 2 constantly changes and so must the angles. I have tried this:

```
moveRectangle.setX(touchEvent.getX());
moveRectangle.setY(touchEvent.getY());
float theta = (float) Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(touchEvent.getY() - 100,touchEvent.getY() - 100));
float velX = (float) (getSpeed() * Math.cos(theta));
float velY = (float) (getSpeed() * Math.sin(theta));
player.move(velX, velY);
```

The above code is constantly run when the user puts his finger on moveRectangle (Point 2) and moves it. But the above code does not work. The player just moves in one of two directions. player.move just adds velX and velY velocity. So how can I get the two angles and move the player in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need just to know velocity on X and Y axis? You can do it without using trigonometry (just use [Pythagorean theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem)).

```
final float deltaX = touchEvent.getX() - player.x; // player.x is point1.x
final float deltaY = touchEvent.getY() - player.y; // player.y is point1.y
final float length = Maths.sqrt((deltaX)^2 + (deltaY)^2);
final float itterations = length / getSpeed();
final float velX = deltaX / itterations;
final float velY = deltaY / itterations;
player.move(velX, velY);
```

Or you need a code of player moving in cycle?

Comment: Why did I not think of that? That's exactly what I needed, thanks.

Comment: One problem though, when I move in an increment of 45 degrees it stops. (Straight up, down, etc...)

Comment: @user2005938, can you show code? Some problems can be in stop checking.

Comment: never mind, I had a piece of code in the player class that stopped movement if there was no velocity.

Answer (score 2):

Would it be easier to approach this problem using a cartesian approach (vectors) versus polar approach (angle and magnitude)? So, if the player is at point `p0` and the "finger" is at point `p1`, then the direction the player should be moving `v` is given by the vector `p1-p0`. You can then scale the resulting vector `v` by the player's speed, and add the player's speed to his position. You can do this easily on a frame-by-frame basis.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Math.toDegrees()`.

From the `Math.sin()` / `cos()` Javadoc:

Parameters:

- a - an angle, in radians.

Returns:

- the sine of the argument.